# Unable to edit created opportunity

Tags: authorization

I'm unable to edit the opportunity i created and unsure abt the auth or security profiles. how can i fix the issue? any inputs please?

Insufficient Privileges
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

Comment: Are you an admin? If not, I would suggest reaching out to the admin. If you are an admin, maybe the edit button is overridden and you do not have access to the VF page it is redirecting to?

Comment: i think you are right, the page is overriden with a custom vf page....where shud i go to set the auth for custom vf page?

Comment: wud it be in profiles?

Comment: Great. Added as an answer to your can mark it as accepted and close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are an admin, maybe the edit button is overridden and you do not have access to the VF page it is redirecting to?

Setup -> Develop -> Pages / Visualforce Pages -> Find the page

Click Security
Add your profile to the list on the right